# Exception thrown on device, but not in simulator

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, debugging

I'm getting very strange behavior when I run my app. In the simulator, the app runs fine. On the device, an exception is thrown. I'm new to iOS, so I'm lost on this one. I have breakpoints set for all exceptions and my output prints only `lldb`.

Also, I'm not sure if this is relevant, but when this first occurred yesterday, my device crashed and deleted all my apps. I had to restore this morning. I tried restarting both my mac and my device.

[image]

Comment: There is a slider at the bottom of the backtrace.  Slide it all the way to the right;  that'll reveal the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Are you referring to the slider in the bottom left? It does nothing when I slide it the right.

Comment: I figured it out, I just had to click the continue button to print the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't realize there is a "continue" button in the console. When clicked, it printed my error.

[image]